# Bad Access Crash When Declaring Blocks Inline of Method Calls

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks, xcode4.5

We were working on some code that was calling an enumeration method:

```
- (void)enumerateRangesOfString:(NSString*)string usingBlock:(void (^)(const NSRange range, volatile BOOL * const stop))block;
```

This all worked fine until we switched over to ARC.

When we looked at the code that was calling it, the app stopped crashing if we uniquely declared the block:

```
id block = ^(const NSRange range, volatile BOOL * const stop) {
                [solutions_ addObject:object];
            };

[[puzzle_ stringForSolution:solution enumerateRangesOfString:word usingBlock:block];
```

When the block was declared in-line the method call, the app crashed. We (I) didn't really know why this would fix the problem, but I went along with it because I didn't want to keep bashing my head against the wall.

The problem is, that this seems to be true of every in-line declaration of blocks when calling a method. My app kept crashing after I added the AFNetworking library to the app. The problem is that I don't really want to go through and change all the code of this library, I'm assuming there is something wrong with my code. This issue continues to cause crashes when I leave the blocks declared inline, and not when I pull the block out and declare it separately.

I use AFNetworking in a couple other apps. Obviously we all know that blocks should be okay to declare inline. Which leads me to conclude that the error isn't in the calling of the method, but somewhere in this project which is crashing.

Comment: Can you show the crashing code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the root cause of your problem is your block parameter really goes out of scope when that method returns. My understanding is that the Apple classes that take a block parameter do a block_copy() right away into an ivar (ie block foo = block_copy(parameter)).